# Ошибка: jQuery.Deferred exception: "имя функции" is not defined ReferenceError: "имя функции" is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ли возможность обойти эту ошибку?

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: getData is not defined ReferenceError: getData is not defined
```

Желательно без изменения `$(function(){` так как внутри куча разного кода

```js
// это в первом файле js
$(function(){
  function getData(){
    console.log('Вызов getData');
  }
});
// это во втором файле js
$(function(){
  getData();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Как я понял ошибка связана с областью видимости

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот возможный вариант решения Вашей проблемы:

```
 // это во первом файле js
$(function() {

  window.getData = function() {
    console.log('Вызов getData');
  }

});

// это во втором файле js
$(function() {
  window.getData();
});
```

Comment: А есть вариант, если допустим к первому файлу нет доступа для редактирования? Точнее он есть, просто со стороннего хостинга, не хотелось бы в нем что то редактировать. Если вариантов нет, то наверное придется

Comment: А есть вариант, если допустим к первому файлу нет доступа для редактирования? - Тогда не получится скорее всего. Как Вы и написали ранее - тут становится уже проблема с областью видимости